# Mock JUnit not detecting any sonar coverage for a method that returns string

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am trying to mock below method with the intention of having sonar coverage -

```
public String getName(String prmTableName) {
        GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = new GetParameterRequest();
        String absParamStorePath = env.getProperty("amazon.aws.parameter") + prmTableName + "/"
                + env.getProperty("amazon.aws.env");
        parameterRequest.withName("/someurl")
        parameterRequest.withName(absParamStorePath).setWithDecryption(Boolean.valueOf(true));
        GetParameterResult parameterResult = awsSimpleSystemsManagement.getParameter(parameterRequest);
        System.out.println("Parameterstore Table Response:  " + parameterResult.getParameter().getValue());
        return parameterResult.getParameter().getValue();
    }
```

Below is my test implementation

```
@Mock
DAO dao

    @BeforeEach
        public void setup(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockmvc= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(dao).build();
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testName(){
    
            String value="";
            when(dao.getName("storeName"))
                    .then(t->value);
    
    
        }
```

but when i ran it through sonar i am getting 0% coverage. Can anyone shed some light on what could be wrong ? I am new to Mockito but i thing what is happening is that test is simply passing on empty value but it is not even hitting the required method along with required parameters.

Comment: are you using spring? Do you have dependency in pom.xml

Comment: how come you don't know if your test is hitting the required method? Can't you print something to confirm?

Comment: @BabyishTank i did confirm in debug mode it is not hitting the method properly i am getting nullpointerexception. But i am passing the required parameter into the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the `getName` method, instance of `DAO` should not be a mock. Mock objects are mainly used to isolate the method under test from its collaborators. Invoking a method from mock instance only does what it is told to do. Actual execution of the method doesn't happen. Hence you are seeing no coverage in sonar.

An actual instance of the `DAO` class must be created to execute the method you are trying to test.

```
DAO dao = new DAO();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in right direction it turned out that after trying your suggestion i did not set env variable due to which i was getting nullpointer exception. After setting that up it worked perfectly

Comment: Glad it helped :)